# RAKE split sentences function on a Python dictionary

Tags: python, regex, csv, nlp, nltk

How would I be able to apply this function to just the values within a python dictionary:

```
def split_sentences(text):
"""
Utility function to return a list of sentences.
@param text The text that must be split in to sentences.
"""
sentence_delimiters = re.compile(u'[\\[\\]\n.!?,;:\t\\-\\"\\(\\)\\\'\u2019\u2013]')

sentences = (sentence_delimiters.split(text))
return sentences
```

The code I have used to create the dictionary from a CSV file input:

```
with open('second_table.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    #Read in the csv file
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    #Skip the headers
    next(reader, None)
    #Iterates through each row to get the key value pairs
    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

The python dictionary looks like so:

```
{'INC000007581947': '$BREM - CATIAV5 - Catia does not start',
 'INC000007581991': '$SPAI - REACT - react',
 'INC000007582037': 'access request',
 'INC000007582095': '$HAMB - DVOBROWSER - ACCESS RIGHTS',
 'INC000007582136': 'SIGLUM issue by opening a REACT request'}
```

Answer (score 1):

mydict.values() gives you all the values in the dictionary. You can then iterate over them and use your function.

```
for value in mydict.values():
    split_sentences(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions, depending on if you want to create a new dictionary or simply update the one you already have.

To update the dictionary values:

```
mydict.update({k : split_sentences(v) for k, v in mydict.items()})
```

To create a new dictionary:

```
new_dict = {k : split_sentences(v) for k, v in mydict.items()}
```